# Angular directives: how to catch events of a nested directive's elements?

Tags: events, angularjs, nested, angularjs-directive

i'm trying to build a directive for a pane-splitter. Simple: pane, divider, pane. The divider is a div that is created by the directive, and it catches the drag and drop events.

Now, basically, it works fine, except that when i have a nested splitter (as you can see in the HTML) - the inner splitter doesn't work. Apparently, the events for the inner divider do not trigger the event handlers at all.

i suspect it is because the event handlers are created, and then, because of the way i remove and re-place the left and right panes, the inner divider i subscribe to is not the one that is eventually stays on the DOM after the directives initialized.

Any thoughts?

Here's the relevant code:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives',[]).directive('splitter', function() {
return {
  restrict: "E",
  transclude: true,
  scope: true,
  template: "<div ng-transclude></div><div style='clear:both'></div><",
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
var pane1, pane2;
if (attrs.orientation.toLowerCase()==="v") {
    pane1 = angular.element(element.find("left")[0]);
    pane2 = angular.element(element.find("right")[0]);
    pane1.css( {
      float:"left"
    });
    pane2.css( {
      float:"left"
    });
  }
scope.pane1 = pane1;
scope.pane2 = pane2;

element.html("");
element.append( scope.pane1).append(scope.divider).append( scope.pane2);
var div = scope.divider;    
div.bind("dragstart", function( ev )  {
  div.css( "opacity", 0.5 );
  ev.stopPropagation();
})
.bind("dragend", function( ev)  {
  scope.pane1.css( "width", ev.x+"px" );
  div.css( "left", ev.x+"px" );
  div.css( "opacity", 1);
  ev.stopPropagation();
});

  },
  controller: function( $scope,$element, $attrs, $transclude ) {
var div = angular.element("<div draggable='true' style='float:left;height:100%' class='vdivider'></div>");
$scope.divider = div;
  }
}
});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<style>
.mycontainer {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.vdivider {
  width: 5px;
  border: 1px double silver;
  background: rgb(200,220,210);
}
</style>

<div class="mycontainer">
  <splitter orientation="v" >
<left>
  left pane
</left>
<right>
  <div class="mycontainer">
    <splitter orientation="v">
      <left>
    bla bla
      </left>
      <right>
    bli bli
      </right>
    </splitter>
  </div>
</right>

  </splitter>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ben Nadel (http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2439-My-Experience-With-AngularJS-The-Super-heroic-JavaScript-MVW-Framework.htm) i understood the problem:

Using element.html("") killed the event handlers (even though i kept the pane objects!). When i used jquery's **detach**  there was no problem.

i think that the more angular-proper way to do this, will be using the $transclude function. If i did that, i might not need to use detach and the jquery library whatsoever. i'll try it sometime....